# Adding an event into calendar Android

Tags: android, events, calendar

I have found this in another topic and it's working fine, it's adding events into my calendar.

```
Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
   beginTime.set(2016, 0, 24, 7, 30);
   Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
   endTime.set(2016, 0, 24, 8, 30);
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
           .setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI)
           .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, beginTime.getTimeInMillis())
           .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime.getTimeInMillis())
           .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Yoga")
           .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group class")
           .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "The gym")
           .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY, CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY);
   startActivity(intent);
```

However, I have a question: Is it possible to "directly" add an event into my calendar? After `startActivity(intent)`, the calendar app pops up and I have to press the button Done (or smth like that) to add the event. So I was wondering if it's possible to add the event directly from my code.

Comment: Check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html), but you will need an additional permission for doing this

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Thanks a lot, I managed to get it to work with ContentResolver and ContentValues